# How to show hidden files in Spotlight search results

Tags: macos, search, finder, spotlight

If I use the search option in the top right corner of the Finder, hidden files do not show up in the search results.  Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about *permanently changing* this, but you can always do that:

Open a Finder window, go to the search box. Here, enter what you're looking for. Then, click the <kbd>+</kbd> button:

[image]

A new bar opens. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button again here. Then, from the left, where it probably says "Last opened date", select "Other…".

In this menu, seaerch for "invisible":

[image]

Check "In Menu" here, and press OK. Now you can search for visible and/or invisible files:

[image]

Of course, you can now save this search to your sidebar to have quicker access.